# Right choice for this time

Tags: jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In few days i am going to start an Ajax based Real State web application in asp.net mvc 3.0

I want to ask, is Razor View Engine ready to use for development and what are the major difference between Razor View Engine and ASPX View Engine i need to remember while developing in Razor View Engine?

Which client side data template plug-in for jquery is more stable an essay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm Asp.net MVC3 is still in Release Candidate:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

These links might help you out with the Razor View Engine:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx

Here a link about the templating engine:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

We're using MVC3 on a large commercial project we plan to release in January. So far, there were almost no issues with MVC3 or with Razor, only a few minor hickups like the syntax highlighter not working correctly at all times.

The unobtrusive client-side validation is a blast and gracefully falls back to server-side validation, which is very neat. However, there might be issues with globalization. We're currently working on that, and I don't know yet how it will turn out.

Razor is a much easier to code and read language, far better than ASPX. Also, the Razor compiler is open source and gives you a better understanding of what is going on than the traditional black-box ASP renderer. Otherwise, there are only minor differences between ASPX and Razor, for example there is no distinction between partial views and views in Razor - you can render views either way.

Comment: Are you using any client template engine?

Comment: yes, jQuery. MVC3 has integrated jQuery support, its unobtrusive client validation uses jQuery.validate.